# Loading views in codeigniter HMVC not working

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

I am trying to load a view from a second controller's view within my first controller but it gives the error that the view cannot be found, even though it is there.

Example
Module -> music
Views -> new  -> file1.php
Views -> old -> file2.php

Controller -> new.php

From within the new.php I am using the function index() and trying to load the view

```
     $this->load->view('old/file2.php');
```

As you can see, I am trying to load the view **file2**(this is from another controller) from within the controller **new** but it does not want to display.

Comment: `.php` on your view call is unnecessary... check manually and confirm that your view is in `system/application/views/old/file2.php`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using the HMVC so the file is located in system/application/modules/music/views/old/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pretty sure you need to add the name of the module:

`$this->load->view('music/old/file2');`

should do it.